# django and bootstrap carousel - use offline

Tags: django

I am using bootstrap offline with :

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
```

in my template, but the code for the first carousel shown here http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

does not work unless I have the CDN links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

what `{% %}` do I need to make carousel work ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. I have got the answer for Offline Carousel for bootstrap.

1. Download > jquery slim build (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js)
2. Copy the contents in your own File as JS file (like copy paste codes in your file and save as jquery.js)
3. Link your script inside body tag (before body tag ends) like...`<script src="jquery.js"></script>`
4. Finally link bootstrap js file as step 3.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

From looking at [the documentation](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), it does not appear that you can use Bootstrap features offline by default. If you look at the [default settings](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html) for `django-bootstrap3`, you will see that this package does use the CDNs behind the scenes.

As far as I know, the only way to use bootstrap offline would be to have a copy of the Bootstrap css and JavaScript files saved on your local machine, as well as the jQuery files, since the Bootstrap JavaScript plugins depend on that.

I have not used `django-bootstrap3` but it looks like if you have a copy of the necessary Bootstrap files stored locally, you should be able to update your Django settings for `django-bootstrap3` to point to these local copies instead of the copies on the various CDNs.